# Send E-mail to printer automatically

Tags: printing, email

I am looking for a way to send a file/web page from my playbook or smart phone to a printer, without using Google Cloud. I used UNIX many years ago and, if I remember correctly, you can configure an account to send all incoming E-mails to the printer.

Is it possible to do this with Ubuntu? If yes, can it also be setup to limit by the sender name?

Comment: If you are using Thunderbird you may give it a try this addons [autoprint](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/autoprint2/)

Comment: you can print file by `lp` command.  you can scan incoming maildir folder (your client need to store each mail in separate file) and use this command. I think If there was atachment, it must be extracted by munpack or something like that. Now I was inspired to test it :) . It could be posible to pipe mail from exim4 to printer in exim router config.

Answer (score 4):

Using *postfix* and `lp` command

**First Solution: CronJob**

I successfully print incoming mail using this method. I configured postfix for using Maildir by adding this line to `main.cf`:

```
home_mailbox = Maildir/
```

I wrote a short script called `printmails`:

```bsh
maildir="$HOME/Maildir/new/"
for entry in `ls $maildir`; do
    cat $HOME/Maildir/new/$entry | lp -d PRINTER_NAME
    mv $HOME/Maildir/new/$entry  $HOME/Maildir/cur/
done
```

Then I run script for cron.

**Second Solution: Intermediate quick print**

you can add alias for user in `/etc/aliases`:

```
user: "| lp -d PRINTER_NAME"
```

and run

```
newaliases
```

Comment: you can configure script to parse file and print if FROM or SUBJECT is equal your regexp or something.

Comment: Thank you for answering this 5+ year old question that had no answers.  Hopefully this will benefit future readers with the same challenge. Also... Welcome to the Bounty Club! I've made many of my points this way too :)

Comment: This question inspire me to print  automaticaly reports, and having tested solutions i share it ;) maybe someone will search for something like that.